# Find and Remove Objects from Array with Identical Property

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, duplicates, javascript-objects

I have two arrays of objects, one with approx. 1800 items and the second with approx. 600 items. An example of the data in each array:

```
let exampleArray = [{ID:X2346,NAME:"someName"},{ID:X8847,NAME:"someName2"},...]
```

I need to compare the two arrays, and if the 'ID' value from an object in the large array is equal to the ID value from an object in the smaller array, remove the object entirely from the larger array, or leave the larger array with only objects that don't exist in the smaller array based on property 'ID'.

I have done this using two nested for loops, and it works, but I'm trying to improve the speed. I've read up on hash tables but I don't think it can apply to this situation or I am not fully understanding how to use them. Is there a faster way to accomplish my goal?

```
for (let x=0;x<largeArray.length;x++){
  for (let y=0;y<smallerArray.length;y++){
    if(largeArray[x]['ID']===smallerArray[y]['ID']){
      largeArray.splice(x,1)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map all the IDs in the small array with `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
const idsFilter = smallArray.map(item => item.ID);
```

then you can use it to filter out from the large array the items whose ID is included in `idsFilter`, using `Array.prototype.filter()`:

```js
const filteredLargeArray = largeArray.filter(item => !idsFilter.includes(item.ID));
```

Comment: thank you! just tested it a few times and your method is indeed much faster. For my knowledge, why is the map/filter method faster? I thought that under the hood both the map and filter are in some way iterating through the arrays?

Comment: I think the main difference in performance is due to the fact that `Array.prototype.includes()` returns as soon as it finds a match while a nested `for` loop will keep running even if it finds a match and removes it; in other words, you code will _always_ run `largeArray.length` x `smallArray.length` comparisons (approx. 1,080,000 comparisons) [...continue...]

Comment: [...] while with `Array.prototype.includes()` that is only the _maximum_ number of comparisons that will be run, because when a match is found the code will skip comparing the same item with all the other IDs and move to the next item.

Comment: ... I wrote "that is only the _maximum_ number of comparisons that will be run" but what I meant was "that is only the _maximum_ number of comparisons that **could** be run"