# Filter if array include an element of another array

Tags: javascript, filter, javascript-objects

I have two arrays like:

```
arr1 = ["orange","banana"]
arr2 = [{"fruit"= ["pineapple","banana"]},{"fruit"= ["grapes","apple"]},{"fruit"= ["apple","orange"]}]
```

And i need to filter if in second array exists an item of the first.

I am trying to do this:

```
let kFilter = arr1.map(itemY => { return itemY; }); 
let filteredK = arr2.filter(itemX => kFilter.includes(itemX.fruit));
```

But no success :-(

Comment: Hi, you might want to start by fixing syntax errors in your code.

Comment: The code for your `arr2` is not valid JavaScript; did you mean `arr2 = [{"fruit": ["pineapple","banana"]}, ...]` maybe? Having said that, please remember to search before asking, as this question has already been answered several times (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67232917/find-and-remove-objects-from-array-with-identical-property/))

Comment: `arr1.map(itemY => { return itemY; })` doesn't do anything useful (other than cloning `arr1`)

Answer (score 0):

```
//declaration variables correctly
let arr1 = ["orange","banana"]
let arr2 = [{"fruit" : ["pineapple","banana"]},{"fruit" : ["grapes","apple"]},{"fruit": ["apple","orange"]}];

//filter using reduce
arr2.filter((e)=>arr1.reduce((a,i)=>a||e["fruit"].includes(i),false))

//filter using some
arr2.filter((e)=>arr1.some((i)=>e["fruit"].includes(i)))
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.some()`

Answer (score 0):

First to avoid too much iteration convert the simple array to an object something like following. Otherwise the complexity will be high

```
const fruitMap = {
    "orange": 1,
    "banana": 1
};
```

Then you have to iterate over each of the items in second array

```
arr2.forEach(fruitsObj => {
    let arr = fruitsObj['fruit'];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length(); i ++) {
        if (fruitMap[arr[i]]) {
             arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
})
```